# NetBeans 8.1 - I appear to be missing half of Javadoc

Tags: java, javafx-8, netbeans-8

I have installed NetBeans 8.1 and am trying it for my first time (on Windows 7 Home Premium, sp 1), and much of the Javadoc comes up with `"Javadoc not found"`.

I have one platform set up, which has this for source: 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\src.zip
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\javafx-src.zip`

And this for Javadoc: 
`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/`

And for many things, Javadoc come up missing.
Using the Layout sample project from Oracle... 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm

I am looking at LayoutSample.java, here...

```
private void addStackPane(HBox hb) {

    StackPane stack = new StackPane();
    Rectangle helpIcon = new Rectangle(30.0, 25.0);
    helpIcon.setFill(new LinearGradient(0,0,0,1, true, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,
        new Stop[]{
        new Stop(0,Color.web("#4977A3")),
        new Stop(0.5, Color.web("#B0C6DA")),
        new Stop(1,Color.web("#9CB6CF")),}));
    helpIcon.setStroke(Color.web("#D0E6FA"));
    helpIcon.setArcHeight(3.5);
    helpIcon.setArcWidth(3.5);

    Text helpText = new Text("?");
    helpText.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", FontWeight.BOLD, 18));
    helpText.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    helpText.setStroke(Color.web("#7080A0")); 

    stack.getChildren().addAll(helpIcon, helpText);
    stack.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
    // Add offset to right for question mark to compensate for RIGHT 
    // alignment of all nodes
    StackPane.setMargin(helpText, new Insets(0, 10, 0, 0));

    hb.getChildren().add(stack);
    HBox.setHgrow(stack, Priority.ALWAYS);

}
```

And I can get class Javadoc for `Rectangle` and `StackPane`, and moving along, I cannot get Javadoc for `setFill()`, or `setFont()` (in the code sample).  `getChildren()` worked!

Am I missing something? TIA, Mark

Comment: Mine wasn't showing some javaFX docs so I moved the javafx URL before the java8 URL and it all works now.  That doesn't seem to be your problem, but you could try it.

Comment: @brian, I just moved the javafx URL up, and that seems to have done the trick!  Thank you very much for that tip.